# Buffer is merged with another Buffer in TCP Vert.x server

Tags: sockets, tcp, buffer, vert.x

I would like to send commands to server via TCP. I created server which retrieve `Buffers` messages. In client I send 10 commands. I don't know why server reads `Buffer` in not predictable way.

server:

```
@Slf4j
public class TcpServ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer();

        server.connectHandler(socket -> {
            log.debug("New connection established with: socket address {}", socket.remoteAddress());

            socket.handler(new MyHandler());

            socket.closeHandler(v -> {
                log.debug("The socket has been closed.");
            });
        });

        server.listen(8088, "localhost", netServerAsyncResult -> {
            if (netServerAsyncResult.succeeded()) {
                log.debug("Server is now listening on actual port: " + server.actualPort());
            } else {
                log.debug("Failed to bind!");
            }
        });
    }

    @Slf4j
    static class MyHandler implements Handler<Buffer> {

        @Override
        public void handle(Buffer event) {
            byte[] bytes = event.getBytes();
            log.debug("Received data: {}", new String(bytes));
        }

    }

}
```

client:

```
@Slf4j
public class TcpClie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        NetClient client = vertx.createNetClient();

        client.connect(8088, "localhost", netSocketAsyncResult -> {

            log.debug("Connection established.");

            NetSocket socket = netSocketAsyncResult.result();

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                String s = "Command" + j;
                Buffer b = Buffer.buffer(s.getBytes());
                socket.write(b);
            }

            log.debug("Data sent.");

            socket.handler(buffer -> {
                log.debug("Recived data from server with size: " + buffer.length());
            });

        });

    }

}
```

What I got is once:

```
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command0Command1Command2Command3Command4Command5Command6Command7Command8Command9
```

another time is:

```
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command0
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command1
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command2
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command3
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command4Command5
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command6Command7
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command8
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command9
```

What I expect is every time I use `socket.write()` server recive `Buffer`.
Expected output should be:

```
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command0
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command1
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command2
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command3
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command4
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command5
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command6
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command7
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command8
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG TcpServ$MyHandler - Received data: Command9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. TCP is a low-level protocol, it does not define what is a *request* or *command* like HTTP does.

You must define your own application protocol on top of TCP, which can be as simple as adding the newline `\n` character between them, or having a fixed buffer size for all commands.

On the server side, you could then use the Vert.x [`RecordParser`](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_record_parser):

```
RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", h -> {
  System.out.println(h.toString());
});

parser.handle(Buffer.buffer("command0\ncomma"));
parser.handle(Buffer.buffer("nd1\nco"));
parser.handle(Buffer.buffer("mmand2"));
```

Will result in:

```
command0
command1
command2
```